# PHP Error SoapClient getProxy()

Tags: php

Getting this error while using soap service php :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("getProxy") is not a valid method for this service in C:\webserver\www\feeder\index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\webserver\www\feeder\index.php(7): SoapClient->__call('getProxy', Array) #1 C:\webserver\www\feeder\index.php(7): SoapClient->getProxy() #2 {main} thrown in C:\webserver\www\feeder\index.php on line 7
```

here's my code :

```
<?php 
$wsdl = "http://localhost:8182/fg/live.php?wsdl";

$username = "aaaaa";
$password = "123456";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$proxy = $client->getProxy();

$token = $proxy->GetToken($username, $password);
var_dump("Get Token = ".$token);

$table = $proxy->ListTable($token);
var_dump("Tabel = ".$table);
?>
```

There's something wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the [PHP SoapClient Doku](http://php.net/manual/de/class.soapclient.php), there is no getProxy-Method. The client itself calls the functions defined in wsdl:

```
$token = $client->GetToken();
$client->ListTable($token);
```

And make shure, that you check $token, if it's really a single variable, or if it is an object.